# Cannot redirect output of command to file when called by keyboard shortcut in Cinnamon

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I can call this from the terminal:

```
echo 'hello' > ~/Desktop/testing
```

And I get the expected output.

However, when I try to create a keyboard shortcut in Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.3 (via System Settings -> Keyboard -> Custom Shortcuts), I do not get the expected output after calling the shortcut.

What's going on here and how can I make a shortcut for the command above?

Comment: What, if any, output do you get then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common problem. Many "exec" system won't support redirection. Such case you can always wrap your commands in bash (or sh):

```
bash -c "echo 'hello' > ~/Desktop/testing"
```